# How to correctly initialize many to many relationship with code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

I'm trying to use `code-first` to model my db.

What I'm trying to map here is a `0 -> *` relationship for `Users` and `Challenges`.

E.g A user can have 0 or more challenges associated with them. A challenge can have 0 or more users associated with them.

This is the code I'm using, the problem is that the challenges table is generated with a `UserAccount_ID` property.

```
public class UserAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Challenge> Challenges { get; set; }
}

public class Challenge
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChallengeId {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Competitor> Competitors { get; set; }
}

public class Competitor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

And the incorrect property:

[image]

I've tried adding this to my context class but it doesn't have any effect:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<UserAccount>()
        .HasMany(o1 => o1.Challenges)
        .WithOptional();

    base.OnModelCreating(mb);
}
```

**Edit**

Updated title and question - relationship is not zero to many but many to many.

Comment: "A user can have 0 or more challenges associated with them. A challenge is totally independant of users." Isn't that a **many-to-many** relationship?

Comment: You're probably right - I'm quite new to EF and SQL in general... I'm trying to say that users *can* have challenges - and the challenges have no ties to users whatsoever

Comment: If you saying "A user can have 0 or more challenges associated with them. A challenge is totally independant of users.", then the 2nd sentence is wrong in the meaning of relationships. And as I understood, in your case you need "many-to-many". You can change 2nd sentence to "A challenge in its turn also can have 0 or more users associated with it". In that case it will be may-to-many relationship between user and challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That column comes from your relationship between `Challenge` and `UserAccount`. You could declare the FK property in your model:

```
public class Challenge
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChallengeId {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //Add these properties
    public int UserAccountId{get;set;}
    public UserAccount UserAccount{get;set;}

    public virtual List<Competitor> Competitors { get; set; }
}
```

By default EF use some name conventions to identify the FK properties in your model, so it should be fine with that name. Now, if you are using Fluent Api, then I suggest to configure the relationship as you are intending to do:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<UserAccount>()
        .HasMany(o1 => o1.Challenges)
        .WithOptional(e=>e.UserAccount);
        .HasForeignKey(e=>e.UserAccountId);

    base.OnModelCreating(mb);
}
```

Now if you don't want to include the FK property and the navigation property in your Challenge entity but you want to rename the FK property you can do this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<UserAccount>()
        .HasMany(o1 => o1.Challenges)
        .WithOptional();
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserAccountId"));

    base.OnModelCreating(mb);
}
```

Thinking a little more about your model it is true that maybe what you are really pursuing is a many to many relationship, if that if the case you can configure this way:

```
  mb.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasMany(r => r.Challenges)
    .WithMany() // No navigation property here
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("UserAccountId");
            m.MapRightKey("ChallengeId");
            m.ToTable("UserAccountChallenge");
        });
```

Comment: I may have gotton the question wrong - I don't want the `Challenge` entity to have any properties tieing it to an individual user

Comment: Ok, in that case I think you need to decide which of the last two proposal works better for you. Anyway whatever your choose the FK column will be created because is the way to related tables. If you use the last option the junction table will be not part of your model

Comment: Yep I think the last option is the one I want - great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple Conventions for achieving `Many to Many` and `One to Many` relationship in `entity framework`. Will try to mention all .Hope these will be helpful.

**UPDATE (as OP wants Many to Many):** **MANY to MANY Relationship**

**Convention 1 :**

> Collection navigation properties in both models

```
public class UserAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Challenge> Challenges { get; set; }
}
    public class Challenge
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ChallengeId {get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }

   public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

Other ways for acheiving the same

```
mb.Entity<UserAccount>()
.HasMany(r => r.Challenges)
.WithMany()
.Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("UserAccountId");
        m.MapRightKey("ChallengeId");
        m.ToTable("UserAccountChallenge"); //Junction Table
    });
```

**ONE to MANY Relationship**

**Convention 1:**

> This can be achieved by including reference navigation property of
>   type `UserAccount` in the `Challenge`

```
    public class Challenge
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChallengeId {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public UserAccount UserAccount{get;set;}    
}
```

**Convention 2:**

> Another convention is to include collection navigation property in
>   `UserAccount`

```
public class UserAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Challenge> Challenges { get; set; }
}
```

**Convention 3:**

> Including navigation property at both ends will also result in
>   one-to-many relationship

```
public class Challenge
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string ChallengeId {get; set;}
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

public UserAccount UserAccount{get;set;}    
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Challenge> Challenges { get; set; }
}
```

**Convention 4:**

> Fully defined relationship at both ends will creates one-to-many
>   relationship

```
public class Challenge
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string ChallengeId {get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }

  public int UserAccountId { get; set; }
  public UserAccount UserAccount{get;set;}    
}
```

> Configure One-to-Many Relationship using Fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // configures one-to-many relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
        .HasRequired<Challeng>(s => s.ChallengId)
        .WithMany(g => g.UserAccount)
        .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.ChallengId); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - sorry I wasn't clearer in my original question